# Problem with routing tables network interface in Centos 6.6

Tags: centos, hostname, network-interface, route

I've problem with the routing tables, I've 2 network interface.

(2 interfaces with 2 difference network address IP address: 112.xxx.xxx.xxx: static IP and 10.xxx.xxx.xxx local IP)

1: IP address is: AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA/24, defaut gateway: AAA.AAA.AAA.1  (auto_eth3)
 2: IP address is: BBB.BBB.BBB.BBB/24, default gateway: BBB.BBB.BBB.1  (auto_eth0)

the problem is I can use the auto_eth3 to connect to Internet but the local machine with auto_eth0 cannot ping to this computer (this computer can ping to local machines).

I've seen the routing tables, it only show that (this mean that this interface go to the default gateway but cannot see the default gateway for Auto_eth3)

```
0.0.0.0         112.xxx.xxx.xxxx   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 Auto_eth0
```

What is my problem? Please help for me to the local machines (10.xxx.xxx.xxx) can ping to my computer (BBB.BBB.BBB.BBB)

Thanks

Comment: You can't have two gateways this way. You will have to work with ip rules and in some cases, with packet marking - http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html - And, avoid using `route` and `ifconfig`. Those comands are in process of deprecation. :)

Answer (score -1):

For me its not very clear how is your network architecture, Refer following tutorial it is some what similar to your requirement. [Linux Route Command Examples (How to Add Route in Linux)](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/route-examples/)

refer *A Sample Network Architecture* section in that tutorial. Still if is not helping, re-frame your question with exact IP details and route output without XXX of both local machine and centos

Comment: `route`  command is pretty old on Linux(deprecated) and shall not be used anymore - https://dougvitale.wordpress.com/2011/12/21/deprecated-linux-networking-commands-and-their-replacements/ .

Comment: my comment for who ever down voted, agree route is deprecated and good to use ip, but I don't mind using route command to display route information,its not going to harm/corrupt the OS if we type route command. My intention was to give some help, something is better than nothing.

Comment: not judging your help. your answer seems to be a comment than an answer itself. It is better to use comments when the one is asking didn't provide enough information. I know you can't comment, so: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Comment: ok, got it. I will take care next time.